# Parsing XML in Swift 4

Tags: xml, swift, xml-parsing

I'm new to XML parsing in Swift and I found this code on [Parsing XML from URL in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31083348/parsing-xml-from-url-in-swift/31084545#31084545) but I get a `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION` error when I try running the code. The description of the error reads: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

This is my simple XML file:

```
<xml>
    <book>
        <title>Book Title</title>
        <author>Book Author</author>
    </book>
</xml>
```

The following code creates an `XMLParser` object and parses the XML file located in my Documents.

```
// get xml file path from Documents and parse

let filePath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).last?.appendingPathComponent("example.xml")

let parser = XMLParser(contentsOf: filePath!)
parser?.delegate = self

if (parser?.parse())! {
    print(self.results)
}
```

Here I implement the `XMLParserDelegate` methods and define my dictionaries:

```
// a few constants that identify what element names we're looking for inside the XML

let recordKey = "book"
let dictionaryKeys = ["title","author"]

// a few variables to hold the results as we parse the XML

var results: [[String: String]]!          // the whole array of dictionaries
var currentDictionary: [String: String]!  // the current dictionary
var currentValue: String?                 // the current value for one of the keys in the dictionary

// start element
//
// - If we're starting a "record" create the dictionary that will hold the results
// - If we're starting one of our dictionary keys, initialize `currentValue` (otherwise leave `nil`)


func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String] = [:]) {

    if elementName == recordKey {

        currentDictionary = [String : String]()

    } else if dictionaryKeys.contains(elementName) {

        currentValue = String()

    }
}

// found characters
//
// - If this is an element we care about, append those characters.
// - If `currentValue` still `nil`, then do nothing.

func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {

    currentValue? += string

}

// end element
//
// - If we're at the end of the whole dictionary, then save that dictionary in our array
// - If we're at the end of an element that belongs in the dictionary, then save that value in the dictionary


func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {

    if elementName == recordKey {

        results.append(currentDictionary)
        currentDictionary = nil

    } else if dictionaryKeys.contains(elementName) {

        currentDictionary[elementName] = currentValue
        currentValue = nil

    }
}

// Just in case, if there's an error, report it. (We don't want to fly blind here.)

func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, parseErrorOccurred parseError: Error) {

    print(parseError)

    currentValue = nil
    currentDictionary = nil
    results = nil

}
```

The error is found on the `didEndElement` method when the `currentDictionary` is appended to the `results` dictionary.

```
func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {

    if elementName == recordKey {

        results.append(currentDictionary)    // Line with Error
        currentDictionary = nil

    } else if dictionaryKeys.contains(elementName) {

        currentDictionary[elementName] = currentValue
        currentValue = nil

    }
}
```

Please help me solve this issue. I'm using the exact same code provided on [Parsing XML from URL in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31083348/parsing-xml-from-url-in-swift/31084545#31084545) and they don't seem to have any issues. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54075082/7408519

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code never actually initializes `results` so the first time you try to use it you are trying to force-unwrap an `nil` optional value. That's bad. And there's no reason to declare it as an implicitly unwrapped optional.

You need to change:

```
var results: [[String: String]]!
```

to:

```
var results = [[String: String]]()
```

You will also need to remove the line:

```
results = nil
```

from your `parser(_:parseErrorOccurred:)` method.

If you would rather have `results` be optional then you can make the following changes to your code:

Change the declaration of `results` to:

```
var results: [[String: String]]? = [[String: String]]()
```

Change:

```
results.append(currentDictionary)
```

to:

```
results?.append(currentDictionary)
```

And you leave the `results = nil` line in `parser(_:parseErrorOccurred:)`.

Comment: @Rob Thanks. My initial answer focused more on the cause of the crash without looking at the bigger picture. Your comment is a good one and my answer now reflects both possible approaches.

Comment: I knew it was an initiation problem and I tried it without it being optional and it didn't work. This makes way more sense! Thank you guys! @rob

Answer (score 1):

rmaddy has correctly diagnosed the problem (+1). The `results` was never initialized.

I would suggest leaving your code largely as is, but merely add a [`parserDidStartDocument`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/xmlparserdelegate/1412065-parserdidstartdocument) method that initializes `results` as follows:

```
func parserDidStartDocument(_ parser: XMLParser) {
    results = [[:]]
}
```